# Cordova Android Push Notification With Action Button

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I have used [Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) , when i am sending push with action button 1)accept 2)ignore.

when notification came , i was clicked on "accept" button . but i want parameters with the "accept" button callback. from that i will identify with notification's "accept" was called.

code reference

```
//initialization of push object
        var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "alert": "true",
                "senderID": CONFIG.PROJECT_NUMBER,
                "icon": "img/ionic.png",
                "iconColor": "blue",
                "badge": "true"
            },
            "ios": {
                "alert": "true",
                "badge": "true",
                "sound": "true"
            }, 
            "windows": {

            } 
        });

        //listner for getting registration detail of device
        push.on('registration', function(data) {
            device_id_for_push=data.registrationId;
        });

        //listner called on new push notification
        push.on('notification', function(data) {
            // app.onPushAccept(data);
            alert("on notification");
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        //error listner
        push.on('error', function(e) {
            // alert(e);
            // alert("push error");
        });

        app.onPushAccept=function(data){
            alert("onPushAccept")
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            // cordova.plugins.notification.badge.clear();
            // cordova.plugins.notification.badge.increase();
        }
```

in code "app.onPushAccept" function is callback of "accept" button..

Please help me as soon as possible.
Thank You..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Push Notification (Only)

Step 1 - First of all go to given below directory

```
     plugins > phonegap-plugin-push > src > android > com > adobe > phonegap > push
```

Step 2 - Open GCMIntentService.java File from above directory

Step 3 - Determine function calling "createActions" and 
         Add actual parameter "requestCode" like...

```
     createActions(extras,mBuilder,resources,packageName,notId,requestCode);
```

Step 4 - Determine function definition "createActions" and 
         Add formal parameter "int requestCode" like...

```
     private void createActions(Bundle extras, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, Resources resources, String packageName, int notId,int requestCode)
```

Step 5 - In function definition "createActions" and inside for loops 
         Change second parameter from "i" to "requestCode" like...

```
     pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

     pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Step 6 - After completing above all steps remove android platform if already added platform Then add android platform.

Sorry and improve if any mistake founds in my solution.

Comment: Is there any way to implement something like this if we are using ionic? I don't want to meddle with the plugins folder in order to implement this.

Comment: Saying that because this folder is generated during building the apk in case of ionic. In other words, can I get the way to do this by changing something (or adding) in config.xml and/or package.json?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first imagine you are sending the following payload:

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["my device id"],
    "data": {
        "title": "My title",
        "message": "My message.",
        "actions": [
            { "title": "Accept", "callback": "app.accept", "foreground": true},
            { "title": "Ignore", "callback": "app.ignore", "foreground": false}
        ]
    }
}
```

and you have setup the following action button handlers:

```
app.accept = function(data} {
  // do something
}

app.ignore = function(data} {
  // do something
}
```

so now you have two options you can either put something in the push payload that uniquely identifies the push that was received which will be put in data.additionalData or modify the callbacks to call another event handler:

```
app.accept = function(data} {
  app.processPush('accept', data);
}

app.ignore = function(data} {
  app.processPush('ignore', data);
}

app.processPush = function(type, data) {
  if (type === 'accept') {
    // do accept stuff
  } else if (type === 'ignore') {
    // do ignore stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [navigator.notification.confirm](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/index.html#navigatornotificationconfirm) method of the plugin [cordova-plugin-dialogs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/index.html#navigatornotificationconfirm)

it displays a customizable confirmation dialog box.

**Syntax**

```
navigator.notification.confirm(message, confirmCallback, [title], [buttonLabels])
```

- **message**: Dialog message. (String)
- **confirmCallback**: Callback to invoke with index of button pressed (1, 2, or 3) or when the dialog is dismissed without a button press (0). (Function)
- **title**: Dialog title. (String) (Optional, defaults to Confirm)
- **buttonLabels**: Array of strings specifying button labels. (Array) (Optional, defaults to [OK,Cancel])

you can change **buttonLabels** to ["Accept","Ignore"]
to satisfy your needs.

**Example**

```
function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
    alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
}

navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!', // message
     onConfirm,            // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',           // title
    ['Accept','Ignore']     // buttonLabels
);
```

Comment: i had identified that i was clicked on "accept" button. but i want to pass params from server to my callback of "accept" button

Comment: @EjazMafat you can't  pass from server to callback, I think you should make a server call using $.get or $.ajax to get those params so that you can pass it.